Getting code 2 while building with dockerfile
I had a working dockerfile, but I wanted to upgrade it so that the container would not run from the root user. Here is the initial version of the dockerfile:
FROM something/openjdk-17:1.13-1

WORKDIR /opt/app

COPY ./build/libs/*.jar app.jar

CMD java ${JAVA_OPTS:- -Xmx1G} -jar app.jar

Then, I tried to add a user, grant him rights and run the container on his behalf.
FROM something/openjdk-17:1.13-1

RUN adduser -D myuser && chown -R myuser /opt/app
WORKDIR /opt/app

COPY ./build/libs/*.jar app.jar

USER myuser
CMD java ${JAVA_OPTS:- -Xmx1G} -jar app.jar

However, I got:
The command '/bin/sh -c adduser -D myuser && chown -R myuser /opt/app' returned a non-zero code: 2
Process exited with code 2

What could be the problem?

(You don't actually need to chown the directory.  It's fine if the container's runtime user can't write to the current directory, and it's probably good practice to keep the code in the container from being overwritten accidentally.)

The best way to debug problems like these is to run a raw image first with attached terminal, and then go through the steps manually until you've got them right.

3 problems in your Dockerfile:

Trying to give permission before creating directory (opt/app). Please move WORKDIR /opt/app before chown
Please use useradd instead of adduser
Please be careful about which user you are adding (you added trmonbs, but used myuser)

Sample (Dockerfile):
FROM openjdk:11

WORKDIR /opt/app

RUN useradd -r myuser && chown -R myuser /opt/app

COPY *.jar app.jar

USER myuser

CMD java ${JAVA_OPTS:- -Xmx1G} -jar app.jar

Creating myuser with root rights:
RUN useradd -r -g root myuser && chown -R myuser:root /opt/app

Output:
PC:~/javatest$ docker build -t testjdk .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  6.656kB
Step 1/6 : FROM openjdk:11
 ---> 47a932d998b7
Step 2/6 : WORKDIR /opt/app
 ---> Running in eaad102b776e
Removing intermediate container eaad102b776e
 ---> 1937a6e2eed8
Step 3/6 : RUN useradd -r myuser && chown -R myuser /opt/app
 ---> Running in fc0d7c5ebc1d
Removing intermediate container fc0d7c5ebc1d
 ---> 56ddcf8fbbb4
Step 4/6 : COPY *.jar app.jar
 ---> 9004394fd9d9
Step 5/6 : USER myuser
 ---> Running in ae35fb0fc285
Removing intermediate container ae35fb0fc285
 ---> 797ee3ec3215
Step 6/6 : CMD java ${JAVA_OPTS:- -Xmx1G} -jar app.jar
 ---> Running in e5f3814f11a7
Removing intermediate container e5f3814f11a7
 ---> 676d4cdc37d8
Successfully built 676d4cdc37d8
Successfully tagged testjdk:latest
PC:~/javatest$ docker run testjdk
My Java App

Output2 (to check whether it has root rights or not, after adding myuser with root rights):
PC:~/javatest$ docker run -it --rm testjdk2 bash -c 'id && exec bash'
uid=999(myuser) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
myuser@b9a82e60eff2:/opt/app$ 


Thanks! But, now I get "permission denied" (code 1) in the same line where code 2 was before. I understand that I have to create a user with root rights, how can this be done?

I added into the post, myuser with root right, pls use "RUN useradd -r -g root myuser && chown -R myuser:root /opt/app"

Unfortunately, permission is still denied :(

Anyway, getting "cannot lock /etc/passwd"
